# How to aggregate DataFrame based on binnary and numeric columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, aggregation, melt

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
ID   | VAR1 | VAR2 | C1   | C2
-----|------|------|------|-------
111  | 1    | 0    | 12   | 0
222  | 1    | 1    | 11   | 18
333  | 0    | 1    | 6    | 5
444  | 1    | 0    | 7    | 2
```

And as an output I need somethin like below:

- If someone has '1' in VAR1 sum his values in C1 --> column "C1" below
- If someone has '1' in VAR2 sum his values in C2 --> column "C2" below

  | COL1 | C1 | C2 |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | VAR1 | 30 | 20 |
  | VAR2 | 17 | 23 |

How can I do such aggregation in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `dot`

```
out = df.filter(like = 'VAR').T.dot(df.filter(like = 'C'))
Out[267]: 
      C1  C2
VAR1  30  20
VAR2  17  23
```

Comment: Hmm, almost good, but what if in my real DataFrame VAR1, VAR, C1, C2 have totally different not similar names, in taht case we can not use filer and like, maybe you can modify our code to implement list of variables ?

Comment: `listofvar = [] , listofc = [] ,df[listofvar].T.dot(df[listofc])` @unbik

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much BENY, I gave you best answer! :)